# MySQL: how to pick the smallest integer that isn't a zero

Tags: mysql, select

I feel like this would be easy but it's proving harder than it should.

Currently, I have several price fields for each record in a table (sale_price, retail_price, discounted_price, other_price) but I would like to get only the highest and lowest non-zero values.

This works fine for highest value:

```
SELECT GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price, discounted_price, other_price) AS highest_price FROM TABLE
```

However, fields in the database that don't have values are stored as zeros so finding the smallest value that isn't a zero is proving challenging. This doesn't work:

```
SELECT LEAST(retail_price, sale_price, discounted_price, other_price) AS lowest_price FROM TABLE
```

as it returns a zero.

Is there an easy way to grab a non-zero smallest value from a list with a simple modification to the statement?

Any help/nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Example data:

```
stock_number    discounted_price    sale_price      retail_price    other_price
1               999                 888             0               777
2               55                  22              33              11
3               0                   0               0               0
```

What the ideal filtered result should be:

```
stock_number    highest_price       lowest_price
1               999                 777
2               55                  11
3               0                   0
```

Comment: Is it possible that all fields in a row are zeroes?

Comment: give a sample data value and sample result

Comment: If your data is bad, might be time to fix your data.

Comment: I don't have access to test, but could you just add a where condition to only consider values > 0?  `... WHERE retail_price >0 AND sale_price>0 AND...`

Comment: The data isn't bad. Even if the fields were set to NULL instead of zero, **LEAST** will return NULL instead of the lowest non-null non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IF` condition to return the highest possible integer if the number is equal to zero. I used modulo instead of an additional `IF` for `IF output is ~0>>32 return 0`.

```
SELECT *, LEAST(IF(retail_price>0,retail_price,~0>>32),
 IF(sale_price>0,sale_price,~0>>32), 
 IF(discounted_price>0,discounted_price,~0>>32), 
 IF(other_price>0,other_price,~0>>32))%(~0>>32)
AS lowest_price FROM table_name;


+--------------+------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| retail_price | sale_price | discounted_price | other_price | lowest_price |
+--------------+------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
|       434.28 |    6992.52 |          8969.79 |    11526.37 |       434.28 |
|      6032.47 |    7928.27 |          9198.91 |     9864.75 |      6032.47 |
|      9382.03 |    4970.88 |          9053.33 |     5664.02 |      4970.88 |
|      1160.12 |    1153.51 |          2287.21 |     7975.51 |      1153.51 |
|      8325.92 |    5358.05 |          1812.52 |     5333.46 |      1812.52 |
|      8884.71 |    3733.20 |          4356.84 |    10584.62 |      3733.20 |
|      2817.57 |    7023.99 |          1977.24 |     1159.22 |      1159.22 |
|     12209.40 |    8189.34 |          4318.52 |     9369.54 |      4318.52 |
|      9202.18 |    5557.26 |           179.77 |     8917.08 |       179.77 |
|         0.00 |       1.00 |             2.00 |        3.00 |         1.00 |
|       100.00 |     201.00 |           302.00 |        0.00 |       100.00 |
|         0.00 |       0.00 |             0.00 |        0.00 |         0.00 |
+--------------+------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This actually returns NULL instead of the lowest non-zero value from the list.

Comment: I am so sorry! Please use `~0`. :)

Comment: This now returns a -1 :(

Comment: @rationalboss your idea is good, but `~0` returns approximately `2^64` (18,446,744,073,709,552,000 instead of the exact 18,446,744,073,709,551,616), which I suspect is being read into OP's code as a 32-bit integer with the sign bit set. Try replacing `~0` with a large enough number, say `999999`

Comment: @kam Try replacing all the `~0` with `999999`

Comment: @KamranKhan or ~0>>32

Comment: This might be a tricky but useful alternative although it still doesn't fully answer the initial question since it will return **99999** instead of **0** in cases where all values are **0**.

Comment: It doesn't look very nice but my updated answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
SELECT GREATEST(discounted_price,sale_price,retail_price,other_price)
as highest_price,
LEAST(discounted_price,sale_price,retail_price,other_price) as lowest_price
FROM TABLE
WHERE retail_price > 0 AND sale_price > 0;
```

Comment: Someone already suggested this below you and I've told them in a comment why this doesn't work since it filters rows by prices where as I need all the rows returned but just with price fields modified.

Comment: did you check with "SELECT *," ?

Comment: **WHERE** fetches rows that meet a particular condition. The initial question isn't to filter results but to simply compute the highest and lowest values in every row returned. `SELECT LEAST(a, b) as c WHERE a > 0 AND b > 0` will remove every row where `a = 0` and `b = 0` as opposed to returning the row with the lowest non-zero value as c.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQL is lacking any filter functionality that's making this harder than necessary. How about this:

```
SELECT
  LEAST(
    IF(!retail_price,
       0,
       retail_price - GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price,
                               discounted_price, other_price)),
    IF(!sale_price,
       0,
       sale_price - GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price,
                             discounted_price, other_price)),
    IF(!discounted_price,
       0,
       discounted_price - GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price,
                                   discounted_price, other_price)),
    IF(!other_price,
       0,
       other_price - GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price,
                              discounted_price, other_price))
  )
  + GREATEST(retail_price, sale_price, discounted_price, other_price)
  AS lowest_price
FROM
  `TABLE`
```

Here's what I did:

Get the least of the following list

- for each column: if column is 0, then 0, otherwise column value - greatest value

If all columns have `0` value, the list will be all `0`s. Otherwise, if at least one column has a non-zero value, it will be a list of values that are `<= 0` because we are subtracting the greatest value from each.

For example, if we originally had these prices:

```
(2, 4, 0, 8)
```

The resulting list, given greatest value is `8` and we're subtracting it from all except `0`s, will be

```
(-6, -4, 0, 0)
```

Note that `0` is now the greatest number, so we can easily exclude it by finding the `LEAST` from this list. The `LEAST` number from this list will also be the lowest number from our original set, minus the `GREATEST` number we subtracted.

So, we add the greatest number back to get its original value.

Again, if all of them were `0` originally, that's going to be `0`. Otherwise, it's going to be the original least value greater than `0`, which is exactly what we wanted.